# Change background color of links used to modify div show/hide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a navigation list:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">Contact Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

When Home or Contact is clicked, the respective div is hidden or shown.

```
<script>

$("#tabs a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".toggle").hide();
    var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
    $(toShow).show();
});

</script>

<div id="home" class="toggle" style="display:none"> This is the Home page.</div>
```

**Question**

How do I make the background of the word in the navigation list different when its corresponding div is shown?

E.g. When the div "home" is shown, the word "Home" in the navigation has a blue background.

Comment: With CSS... I'm not seeing where you have problems.

Comment: @gdoron - So, how do I do it? What keyword to google for?

Comment: Never mind, I answered it with an answer + a DEMO, I hope it helps. Good day sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example:

```
$('ul a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find('a').css('background-color', '');

    $(this).css('background-color', 'red')
    return false;
});​
```

[**A DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ECkFB/)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the background color to the clicked element, but you'll also want to make sure to remove it from whichever element was clicked last.

```
$("#tabs a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".toggle").hide();
    var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
    // Remove the class from any siblings if it exists
    $("#tabs a").removeClass('yourClass');
    // Add the class to the clicked #tab a
    $(this).addClass('yourClass');
    $(toShow).show();
});
```

And then create a class in your CSS file (e.g., 'yourClass') that attributes a background color and/or anything else you want to edit it.

```
.yourClass {
    background: #e2e2e2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <script>

    $("#tabs a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(#tabs a).removeClass('yourClass');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(".toggle").hide();
        var toShow = $(this).attr('href');
        $(toShow).show();
    });

    </script>
```

**css**

```
.active
{
background-color:blue;
}
```

hope this helps!!

Comment: This works great. Question: in addition to this, how do I turn "Home" white after I click on "Contact Me"? This turns all the word blue permanently. I suppose I need to $(something).parent()css('background-color','white');. But what do I put in place of "something"?

Comment: Thanks for your help. But gdoron's answer seems to be more concise and spot on. But +1 for your effort.